JWT Tokens for multi-practice inventory application
I am developing a multi practice based inventory management system for hospitals using node.js+express.My application should first verify the practice and then login only specific users registered under that practice. The practice is included in user registration, how do I implement this using the JWT token, what extra fields should I include in my token?
For now I am using a middleware for just verifying the token, I would like to know how to include practice specific details in token, what are the best practices in this case
